# How to show one product by an exact keyword

Tags: google-ads-api, google-shopping

Does someone know how we can show one product by an exact keyword. I will give an example of what we want to achieve:

We have one pink barchair. When someone is looking for pink barchair by Google, Google does not show our pink barchair, but shows a whit and black barchair instead.

Is there a way to only show the pink barchair (so one sku, or product) when someone is looking for a keyword?

Answer (score 1):

The best option for this would be to update your content and make it relevant to specific products, you can update the atl and name tags for the images to say "pink barchair" you will then also have to update the others to "black barchair" and the same with white so that the products don't "clash with each other. It is a very difficult thing to get right as Google does not release much info on how the process works exactly(it's a trade secret) but the most important thing is to make sure that everything is relevant and that each page is specific to an idea/product.

Please keep in mind that you will not see changes immediately after you make them, your cache and cookies also play a part when doing a Google search so its difficult to determine what your customers are seeing

Comment: thanks for your reply and from the answer I do understand that there is not a real way to make this work, only make the content more unique to that product. It is strange that there is not a way how you can say that a curtain product belongs to keywords. Especially because Google doesn't show it right. Probably I will completely ignor that product then (put it by the words to not be found on pink), because in this case we only have on pink barchair

Comment: It is possible but it is a lot of work and consistency across your whole site is key, even then you are not guaranteed to succeed. Just try to keep your product pages specific to products while promoting the company. Otherwise you could get a company that does SEO to try and get your ratings and traffic up as well as improve your search results